# How to move files of a particular date using GREP in UNIX

Tags: linux, shell, unix, grep, timestamp

I have a set of files. I have to select only few which are last modified today using today's date. I can select those files using grep command. But how do I move those files into a new directory?

Comment: Er, why would you use `grep`? `find` is what you want.

Comment: Locking for an answer to a similar problem in the past, I were able to find the answer at [Unix Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/find).

Comment: You should show how you select those file so that one can help with moving them (I mean the code and an example output)

Comment: Multiple approaches are listed here for your above case: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154818/how-to-integrate-mv-command-after-find-command

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
find <source_directory> -not -path '*/\.*' -type f -mtime -1 -print0 \
| xargs -0 -I {} mv {} <destination_directory>
```